# How to make nested indentation in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vimrc

I would like to make if-fi statement in vim, where the `iabbrev` will "autocomplete" the `if-fi` clause:

```
 autocmd Filetype sh iabbrev if if<esc>ma<cr>ifi<esc>`ak
```

which upon `if` generates:

```
if
fi
```

That's correct - I do not have to type `fi` at the end of the clause. So I can continue. For example:

```
if pwd; then
    echo "bla bla"

fi
```

Now below the `echo`, I would like to nest another statement, but this time, If I type `if` it generates:

```
if pwd; then
    echo "bla bla"

    if
fi
fi
```

The second (nested) if-fi broke the indentation. The `fi` ending should be this:

```
if pwd; then
    echo "bla bla"

    if
    fi
fi
```

So the second `if-fi` clause is *withing* the first one. But I have no idea how to achieve that. I have

```
:set autoindent
:set smartindent
```

So vim remember the level of indentation upon `<cr>`, so I can get the right indentation in the nested `if-fi` with one backspace. But I have no idea what key-mapping should I make to achieve that. So what key-mapping should I add to `.vimrc` as `iabbrev` in order to generate the right level of indentation in vim?

Comment: Consider using [vi.se] for your questions on Vim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't reproduce the exact issue you're having, with `filetype=sh` and the indent plug-in enabled it seems to be reinfecting the `fi` to match the `if` for me.

But I can see a problem in your abbreviation in that it's using the `<CR>` in normal mode to move to the next line and then using an `i` to insert the `fi` part. For one thing, it's counting on this next line being empty already (otherwise it will just prepend the `fi` to whatever is already there.) It might also be causing your issue, since inserting on a new line typically doesn't trigger the automatic indentation as inserting a new line (with a `<CR>` in insert mode, or with a normal mode `o` command) would.

My suggestion is to keep in insert mode and use `<C-o>` to execute a single normal mode command to set the mark and move to it. (See [`:help i_CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O).)

This abbreviation should work well:

```
iabbrev if if<C-o>ma<CR>fi<C-o>`a
```

Note that the `<CR>` is happening in insert mode, so it's actually inserting a new line and when a new line is inserted `autoindent` is typically honored.

If you're going to set abbreviations per filetype, you should typically make them buffer-local, so if you have other buffers editing different types of files, they won't apply there. You can do so by adding a `<buffer>` modifier to the command:

```
iabbrev <buffer> if if<C-o>ma<cr>fi<C-o>`a
```

You can then add this to an `autocmd FileTye sh` if you like. If you use an `autocmd`, you'll usually want to keep it inside an `augroup`, so if you source your vimrc file again, it will not duplicate the auto-command and run it multiple times every time the file type is matched.

My usual preference is to let the Vim ftplugin mechanism handle that for me. To do that, just create a file named `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim` and add your `iabbrev <buffer> ...` command directly to it. (Don't add the `autocmd` part.) Vim will handle these automatically, whenever the file type is detected to be `sh`, it will automatically source all these scripts. This makes it simpler to source many rules for a specific file type. You also don't pollute your vimrc with all the filetype-specific rules. Finally, you don't need to worry about escaping those long lines with auto-commands and mappings.